# Salesforce Files Connect Indirect Lookup

Tags: lightning-connect, sharepoint, external-lookup

I set up Salesforce files connect with sharepoint online via an office 365 application and it works fine.

But when i try to do dynamic linking via indirect lookups I do not seem to get it right, I feel like I am missing something.

What i have done so far:

1. Set-up Files connect with sharepoint online & office 365 app(this works 
   fine, the sharepoint site shows up under files and i can access the files)
2. Created a (unique)external ID field on a custom object(indirect lookup)
3. Created an ID field on the document library
4. Created indirect lookup to the custom object.
5. Matched the Sharepoint ID and the ID on the Salesforce object.

This doesn't show the desired documents as a related list on the custom object.

What i feel that might be wrong is the fact that i never had to specify any sharepoint library or list?

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong / forgetting?

External Data source:
[image: External Data source]
External object custom fields & relationships:
[image: External object custom fields & relationships]
Thanks ik advance

Comment: Here is a video made by the Files Connect product manager: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7ByaJxqn4E Does that help?

Comment: Hi Jasper, did you manage to solve this issue? Do you have the right API name of the field from SharePoint in the Indirect Lookup? Are you trying to display the records in Lightning? I think we could have the same issue. Thanks.